# bundling not working

Tags: angularjs, python-2.7, flask, bundling-and-minification

I am new to flask and angularjs. I am trying to use bundle(assets) according to instructions provided [here](http://flask-assets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

I have installed the required jsmin and am calling my filter in the html part accordingly

`{% assets "common_js" %}
    <script src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
{% endassets %}`

Here common_js bundle has been declared and registered.

```
from flask.ext.assets import Environment, Bundle
common_js = Bundle("datepicker.js",filters='jsmin', output='output.js')
assets_env.register('common_js',common_js)
```

The output that I can see on the server terminal is 

`INFO     2015-06-30 02:18:44,606 module.py:790] default: "GET /%7B%7B%20ASSET_URL%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404 2322`

Can anyone point out what I am missing please? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you rendering the template?

Comment: @app.route('/')  def index():  return make_response(open('angular_flask/templates/index.html').read())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the template file but you aren't rendering it.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**update**

When rendering a template, you only need its path relative to your templates folder. You don't need a path relative to the working directory like you do when reading a file with `open`.

Comment: but if i include script tags instead of the bundle, it works fine.

Comment: Because the script tag is HTML. That is handled by the browser. Jinja tags need to be processed by Jinja on the server side. If you look at the source HTML in the browser you will also see the `{% assets ... %}` template tag.

Comment: Now I am getting this error : raise TemplateNotFound(template)  
TemplateNotFound: angular_flask/templates/index.html.

Comment: My guess is you just need `'index.html'`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But now I'm getting this "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: roleProvider <- role" although the js is fetched. Any idea why I could be getting that?

Comment: Sounds like that's related to Angular. Your best bet is to ask that as a new question.